# How to load a possibly undefined template variable with a default value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

Suppose I have a template variable with the name `myvar`.  I know that I can access it in the javascript with `var myvarname = {{ myvar }};`.  However, sometimes `myvar` isn't defined and the above line crashes in that case.  How can I instead load it in with a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the jinja template docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) you can use the `default()` function like:

```
var myvarname ={{ myvar |default('0') }}
```

Or, per [the flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/), you could use an if statement like:

```
{% if myvar  %}
  var myvarname = {{ myvar }};
{% else %}
  var myvarname = 0;
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much; I did not realize that it was possible to use templates in the same section as JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (myvarname == null || myvarname == undefined)
    {
      alert("Default Value");
    }
    else
    {
      alert(myvarname)
    }
```

Maybe this work. First it will check whether variable is undefined/null. If yes, then it will alert you default value.